# Docker registry not pulling images in proxy mode

Tags: docker, proxy, registry

I cant get docker-registry to run in proxy mode. I've set up a registry with the following configuration:

```
version: 0.1
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
proxy:
  remoteUrl: https://index.docker.io/v1
http:
  addr: :5000
  host: https://[DOMAIN]
```

The registry is running in a kube cluster with an exposed service and ingress pointing the deployment.

In my gitlab runner I've set the registry-mirrors array in daemon.json config file to point to this server.

The docker-registry is clear and has no images pushed. However, when I try to run a gitlab job (using node:lts image) I get 404 error from the registry.

This means, my docker gilab runner is trying to pull from my registry proxy, however the proxy cache won't serve the request.

Does the proxy mode should run out of the box, or are there any other manual steps required?

Thanks in advance.

Attaching logs from my registry:

```
10.1.79.1 - - [15/May/2021:18:19:05 +0000] "HEAD /v2/library/node/manifests/lts HTTP/1.1" 404 93 "" "docker/20.10.6 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/8728dd2 kernel/4.15.0-1063-aws os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)"
time="2021-05-15T18:19:05.743476401Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="manifest unknown" err.detail="unknown tag=lts" err.message="manifest unknown" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.host=registry-proxy.bignetwork.dev http.request.id=7bb689b9-f7f0-4bc4-8730-b823737da0b9 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=172.31.0.12 http.request.uri="/v2/library/node/manifests/lts" http.request.useragent="docker/20.10.6 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/8728dd2 kernel/4.15.0-1063-aws os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=1.24767ms http.response.status=404 http.response.written=93 vars.name="library/node" vars.reference=lts
10.1.79.1 - - [15/May/2021:18:19:05 +0000] "GET /v2/library/node/manifests/lts HTTP/1.1" 404 93 "" "docker/20.10.6 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/8728dd2 kernel/4.15.0-1063-aws os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is `remoteurl` not `remoteUrl`. The json fields are case sensitive.

Comment: Ah yeah. Sometimes you just need to ask someone to see the obvious bug after like 6 hrs of debugging :) . Thank you, chaning to remoteurl helped.

Comment: Sometimes you just need that second set of eyes. Thanks for providing enough detail to debug.